# Mule:Routing messages to dead letter exchanges for AMQP endpoint using Mule

Tags: rabbitmq, mule, amqp, mule-component

Using AMQP connectors in mule and trying to achieve a specific use case where if message fails business filtering criteria instead of writing it on output queue it should be routed to dead letter. Suggest Best way to achieve this.
sample code:

```
<mule>
<flow> 
<message source>
<message processor1>
<message processor2>
<message processor3>
<message processor4>
<message processor5>
<amqp:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
</mule>
```

Best way to achieve functionality that if message fails in any message processor subsequent message processor should not execute and message should be forwarded to dead letter exchange of queue. So let say if it fails in message processor 2 message processor 3,4 and 5 should not execute and message should be routed to dead letter exchange. If message does not fail in any stage it should be written to queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AMQP transport](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp/blob/master/GUIDE.md) provides a feature for manual message acknowledgement or rejection ([documentation](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp/blob/master/GUIDE.md#manual-message-acknowledgement-and-rejection)).  If you reject a message, and the queue is configured to use a DLX, then the message will be routed there by the broker.

Try configuring the flow with a catch-exception-strategy as suggested by Victor Romero, and use `<amqp:reject-message />` to reject the message.  Be sure to configure the connector to use `ackMode="MANUAL"`, as well.

Comment: Message processor in my design will be spring beans and specific method will be executed which will contain business logic,if certain logic fails do i need to throw exception and will that be caught by mule catch-exception strategy if catch block is not provided by me in spring bean methods.

Comment: Yes, that's how it will work.  Remember to put a `<amqp:acknowledge-message />` after the component, since you're using `ackMode="MANUAL"`.

Answer (score 1):

To do exactly what you expect just set a catch-exception-strategy with an outbound-endpoint pointing to your DLQ.

However, personally I would rather leverage the rabbit's (or the provider you're using) feature for DLQ: https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html .